# Generating function for sequence $a_n = 5\times 7^n - 3\times 4^n$

Tags: power-series, generating-functions

How would you proceed to find the generating function of the following sequence?
$$a_n = 5\times 7^n - 3\times 4^n$$
I have no idea where to start for cases where the index appears as exponent.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the [wikipedia article of examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Examples_of_generating_functions). The second example (or the second half of the first example, depending on how you're counting) should be able to get you going.

Comment: @Arthur Oh indeed, there's even a basic generating function for $a^n$... Thank you, I'll try this out !

Comment: Okay that was actually super easy, should've found it myself ! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* The sequence satisfies the recurrence $a_{n+2}=11a_{n+1}-28a_n$.

This comes from expanding $(x-7)(x-4)$.